# Using Nuxt with Firestore and GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS for identification

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/ as a base for my project and I am having issues with authentication.

The example uses very complex `auth` section:

```js
      config: {
        apiKey: [api-key-1],
        authDomain: 'nuxt-fire-demo.firebaseapp.com',
        databaseURL: 'https://nuxt-fire-demo.firebaseio.com',
        projectId: 'nuxt-fire-demo',
        storageBucket: 'nuxt-fire-demo.appspot.com',
        messagingSenderId: '807370470428',
        appId: '1:807370470428:web:26da98c86c3fd352',
        measurementId: 'G-XT6PVC1D4X',
        fcmPublicVapidKey:
          [api-key-2]
      },
```

However such complex auth should not be required as with the example here it should be way easier:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault()
});

const db = admin.firestore();
```

This should read the service account info from `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.

How can I use the demo and simplify the auth to use this env var?

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Comment: It wasn't sensitive, this is taken from the example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm literally confused, please pardon me.

1) So you are seeking simple Firebase Authentication right? Since you're bringing up `firebase-admin`, are you trying to bring Firebase SDK into **your server**? (they're both different things)

2) Any particular reason/s why you choose Nuxt instead of Vue, can't just with authentication right?

3) Simple Authentication for Component/VuexStore Documentation for NuxtFire: https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/guide/usage/#examples

4) NuxtFire demo(git repo and site link): https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/guide/demo/

Definitely welcome if I mis-understood your question. Cheers

Comment: 1. In general, I want to use local auth (either with `gcloud auth login` locally or the default service account within running instance in GCP. – 2. I want to use Nuxt for the server side rendering. 3.&4. I already tried that – the excerpt above is from there – I just can't manage it to use the service account instead fo the config variables.